# Deleting multiple tables from SQL Server 2008 using Datalist C#

Tags: c#, sql, multiple-tables

This may seem a common question but I googled to find the right answer that can fix my problem and failed to do so.

I have multiple tables connected to each other by `ProductID` and I wish to delete all data from them when the product from main table has been deleted. i.e.

**Products** : `ProductID - Vender - Description`

**ProductRatings** : `ProductID - Rating - VisitorsCount`

**ProductComments** : `ProductID - VisitorName - Comment`

I read that for such situation a SQL trigger is used but I have no idea about it besides I might be mentioning my DataSource in ASCX.CS file in some cases and in some cases I might simply use `SqlDatasoruce` in ASCX file. Is there any query or stored procedure that can be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to implement a foreign key relationship to `ProductID` and set `on delete cascade`.  This is a general idea:

```
create table ProductRatings
(
    ProductID int not null 
        foreign key references Products(ProductID) on delete cascade,
    Rating int not null,
    VisitorsCount int not null
)
```

What that does is when you delete a primary key value from the `Products` table, that causes SQL Server to delete all records that have a foreign key constraint to that primary key value.  If you do this with your `ProductComments` table as well, problem solved.  No need to explicitly call a `DELETE` on any records in the referencing tables.

And if you aren't using referential integrity...you should.

**EDIT**: this also holds true for `UPDATE`s on the primary key.  You just need to specify `on update cascade`, and the foreign key references will update as the primary key did to ensure RI.

Comment: For data consistency, this is much better than trying to implement a bunch of triggers.  It also encourages the dev to set up proper foreign key relationships in the database.

Comment: Agree with @ChrisLively. In fact, I would go so far as to say triggers should always be a last resort. They often cause more problems than they solve.

Comment: Thank you so much Shark, you not only solved this problem but also gave me great knowledge that will be very useful in future also.... I hope same can work with Insert and Update as well.

Comment: @AliKhan See my edit.  It also worked for `UPDATE`s, but `INSERT`s will explicitly need an `INSERT` into the referencing table, if that makes sense.